# orgmode: set global BABEL parameters?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to setup like the following in the top section of my `.org` file. But it does not work, all the parameters are not passed into the subsequent R code blocks.

```
 #+BABEL: :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes
```

Doing like the following works. But it forces every code block to have `:file` parameter set. I don't want that because I have some code blocks which do not have graphic output.

```
#+PROPERTY: session *R*
#+PROPERTY: cache yes
#+PROPERTY: results graphics
#+PROPERTY: exports both
#+PROPERTY: tangle yes
```

How do I setup this? I prefer one-liner setup like "+BABEL:...." and customize the code blocks that I want differently.

Answer (score 2):

One solution may be to add a PROPERTIES drawer at the heading level e.g.

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes
:END:
```

If you do this, you cannot override individual parameters with another header-args in a PROPERTIES drawer as this overrides the whole line, but you can override indivudal parameters on the #+begin_src declaration.

Comment: This works for all paramenters in there, except for the `session *R*` part. I still have to use the `#+PROPERTY: session *R*` syntax.

Comment: That's odd - I don't use session much (prefer code blocks idempotent) but I can't see a reason why it would be different.  The session arg just gives a name to the session does it not.  Random guess: maybe something else is interpreting the * - can you try calling it something different?

Comment: Can you elaborate your setup? I have no reason to stick to the non-working setup. With that said, reading through the latest orgmode docs, this should work but I haven't tried: ` #+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session *R*`

Comment: I've been using something similar for SQL - this allows me to define the database parameters at the heading level then just write SQL in src blocks and it just works - but I don't need sessions.  The header-args:R syntax is to specifiy particular args are relevent to particular languages - if session in this instance is an R specific arg then that may fix your issue.         :PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :engine "mysql" :dbuser "dbuser" :dbpassword "password" :dbhost "192.168.32.216" :database "dbname" :var dbuser="dbuser" :END:

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to improve on the previous answer:

One solution is to use `#+PROPERTY :header-args:` for file level parameters.  For example:

```
#+PROPERTY: :header-args:R :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes
```

Another solution may be to add a PROPERTIES drawer at the heading level, for example:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:R :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes
:END:
```

Furthermore, you can override :header-args: at lower entries via the [concatenation mechanism](https://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/header-args/#default-header-arguments-shipped-with-org-mode):

```
* Top Level
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:R :session *R* :cache yes :results output graphics :exports both :tangle yes
:END:

** With Overrides
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:R+ :cache no
:END:
```

Similarly, each source block can contain overrides, as well.

I am constantly referring to https://org-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/header-args/ to aid in my babel quests.